# How can "products to be coated" be described?

Tags: adjectives

> Products to be coated (with paint or the like) are set in the coating machine, and the coated products are set in the drying machine.

I am searching for an adjective that can be replaced with "to be coated" in the sentence above I created, because I use the expression "Products to be coated" many times and want more simple expression.

I first thought that "pre-" would be used like "pre-coated products, but I am afraid that "pre-coated" means that it is already coated.

Comment: Are these objects wholly un-coated before ? If yes that word might be appropriate

Comment: Does "that word" refer to "un-coated", not "pre-coated"?

Comment: sorry, yes it refers to ["uncoated"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncoated). You are correct that pre-coated means that it has been coated in preparation for another step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is that there is a difference between katahito's suggestion of "uncoated" and your original "to be coated".  "Uncoated" (or "unpainted", "untreated", etc.) refers to the *current* state of the item.  "To be coated" refers to the intended *future* state of the item.  It's not the same thing, and any other expression may remove that important information.

Meanwhile, "pre-coated" means the item has already had a coat applied, normally as a previous step in the manufacturing process.  Again, not what you are trying to say.

I would not worry too much about repeating the phrase "products to be coated", especially in a description of the manufacturing process.  With technical documentation, it's better to be precise than to write with style.

One option is to use a pronoun like "these", "these products", or "the products", if it's in the same context:

> Products to be coated arrive on the assembly line and checked for defects.  **Those** without defects are set in the coating machine, and then moved to the drying machine.

Comment: I agree that, without additional surrounding context, it's hard to know how to rephrase this. One might be able to simply eliminate "to be coated" altogether, if that could be inferred from the surrounding context: _Products are set in the coating machine, and the coated products are set in the drying machine._